# Return a bool or string inside a Callback in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am writing Unit Testing which require me to hit the exceptions. Incase of promises, I cannot really send any boolean or string values. My intended output and the one I am getting is mentioned below.

```
function mainFunction(registry, name,....){
    justAnotherPromiseFunction(name, function (err, twin) {
        if (err) {          
            return "I want to return a failure message here!";
        } else {
            <MyLogic Goes Here>
        }
    });
}
console.log(mainFunction(registry, name,....));
```

This returns `Promise { <rejected> [ArgumentError: The connection string is missing the property: Something] }`.

Instead of `I want to return a failure message here!`.

Any ideas on how I can manage to do this?

Edit: I am implementing a function from azure sdk that uses promises.
So looks like this:

```
function mainFunction(){
    registry.getTwin(name, function (err, twin) {
        if (err) {          
            return "I want to return a failure message here!";
        } else {
            <My Business Logic Goes Here>
        }
    });
}
console.log(mainFunction());
```

Comment: Your main function does not return anything as you put it. The `console.log` will output `undefined`. Please provide code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Can you post the code of `justAnotherPromiseFunction`, please? Why does it take a callback instead of returning a promise?!

Comment: I've updated the question with a better code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using it in the wrong way. You cannot print the result of promise just by callint it. A promise return its result in the then function.
Please see following examples.

```
async function mainFunction() {
    try {
        const result = await myPromise();
        return result;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return 'I want to return a failure message here!'
    }
}

function myPromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    })
}

it("test async function", async() => {
    console.log(await mainFunction())
})
```

Make your test function async so you can await for the result.

Comment: Hey, one question though. Even if an exception occurs in myPromise , it doesn't invoke the catch block of mainFunction. How can I do so? I want to test a negative scenario for Promise reaching a failure case.

Comment: @Catalyst You can call reject and pass the error here.